# How to ignore string value using unpivot function finding the min value among other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a table looks like this

[image]

The goal is to find a min value among columns `Limit` (Limit1, Limit2,Limit3...etc).

For that, I am using `UNPIVOT` function.

But the problem is that some values are empty strings. As a result the min value becomes empty string.

```
declare @TempTable2 table (ID int, limit1 varchar(50),limit2 varchar(50),limit3 varchar(50),limit4 varchar(50),limit5 varchar(50) )
insert into @TempTable2 values   (1,'1000','1000','3000',NULL, NULL)
                                ,(2,'2000','4000','3000','', NULL)

--select * from @TempTable2
Select  ID, 
        min(Amount) as TheMin
from @TempTable2
    unpivot (Amount for AmountCol in (Limit1,Limit2,Limit3,Limit4,Limit5)) as unpvt
group by ID
```

[image]

So how can I ignore string values when using `UNPIVOT` function?

I would expect my result be like this:

```
ID  TheMin
1   1000
2   2000
```

I tried to use `NULLIF` but `UNPIVOT` doesnt accept it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another options is `NullIf()`

**Example**

```
Select  ID, 
        min(nullif(Amount,'')) as TheMin
from @TempTable2
    unpivot (Amount for AmountCol in (Limit1,Limit2,Limit3,Limit4,Limit5)) as unpvt
group by ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  TheMin
1   1000
2   2000
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your dataType is string type and there is one column contain `''`

You can try to use condition aggregate function in `MIN` and `CAST` to int

```
Select  ID, 
        min(CASE WHEN Amount like '%[0-9]%'  THEN CAST(Amount AS INT)  END) as TheMin
from @TempTable2
    unpivot (Amount for AmountCol in (Limit1,Limit2,Limit3,Limit4,Limit5)) as unpvt
group by ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd1cbe092b3387f816927191aa874231)

```
ID  TheMin
1   1000
2   2000
```

**NOTE**

I would suggest your columns turn to save `int` instead of `varchar` if you only store number in them.